# Fastlane upload to crashlytics fails with error fetching remote file

Tags: crashlytics, fastlane, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

**My Error :** 
Fastlane upload to crashlytics fails with the following error :

> [12:59:37]: Error fetching remote file: Exit status of command 'unzip
>   'C:/Users/xxxx/Library/CrashlyticsAndroid/crashlytics-devtools.zip' -d
>   'C:/Users/xxxx/Library/CrashlyticsAndroid'' was 2 instead of 0.

Archive:  `C:/Users/xxxx/Library/CrashlyticsAndroid/crashlytics-devtools.zip`

warning `[C:/Users/xxxx/Library/CrashlyticsAndroid/crashlytics-devtools.zip]:  30829 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile (attempting to process anyway)`

file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  30829 (attempting to re-compensate)
  inflating:

> C:/Users/xxxx/Library/CrashlyticsAndroid/crashlytics_build.xml
>   error:  invalid compressed data to inflate bad CRC 00000000  (should
>   be 313e1340)

file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  839 (attempting to re-compensate)

file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  839
file #3:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  34909

**Fastlane env :** my fastlane environment is [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12161) https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastlane is not officially supported on Windows (yet). My suggestion is to do this on macOS. (I also commented this on your GitHub issue).

Answer (score 1):

Download the zip from [here](https://fabric.io/download/ant) and extract where fastlane fails to unzip crashlytics-devtools.zip.

For me the path is C:/Users/{your-user}/Library/CrashlyticsAndroid/crashlytics-devtools.zip